# How to fetch Linkedin Post in sharepoint site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, app, newsfeed

I am trying to get Linkedin post in my sharepoint site. For this is there any app available in sharepoint 2013 or i need to use api ..please share step by step process. It will be helpful.

Thanks & Regards
Jhanani

Comment: did you find a solution in the meantime? could you please post it as an answer, as it is also interesting for other people (e. g. me!) :-)